# Unable to follow along the tutorial: Connecting to a data store [11 of 18] | Beginner's Series to: Web APIs with mongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm a beginer on monngoDB and just creating an ASP.NET Web API to perform CRUD operations in a MongoDB database. I've been able to create a simple application based on the following Microsoft tutorial: [beginner's series to  webbbApis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxlKfHGMG-g&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oVjOKgzsWqdFVvzGL2_d72v)

In this tutorial I have Unable to follow along with and have no idea with code on,

**MongoDatabaseOptions.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ContosoRecipes.Models
{
    public class MongoDatabaseOptions
    {
    }
}
```

**IRecipeDataStore.cs**

```cs
using ContosoRecipes.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ContosoRecipes.Data
{
    public interface IRecipeDataStore
    {
         Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetRandomRecipes<T>(int count);
         Task<T> GetRecipeById<T>(string id);
         Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetRecipesById<T>(string ids);
         Task<IEnumerable<T>> SearchRecipesByIngredients<T>(string[] ingredients);
         Task<IEnumerable<T>> SearchRecipesByTags<T>(string[] tags);
         Task UpdateRecipe(Recipe recipe);
         Task RemoveRecipe(string recipe_id);
    }
}
```

**MongoRecipeDataStore.cs**

```cs
using ContosoRecipes.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ContosoRecipes.Data
{
    public class MongoRecipeDataStore : IRecipeDataStore
    {

        public MongoRecipeDataStore(IMongoClient mongoClient, IOptions<MongoDatabaseOptions> mongodbOption, IMongoDatabase database)
        {

        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetRandomRecipes<T>(int count)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetRecipeById<T>(string id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetRecipesById<T>(string ids)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task RemoveRecipe(string recipe_id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> SearchRecipesByIngredients<T>(string[] ingredients)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<IEnumerable<T>> SearchRecipesByTags<T>(string[] tags)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task UpdateRecipe(Recipe recipe)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and a little bit
**ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using ContosoRecipes.Models;

namespace CentosoRecipes
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMongoDb(this IServiceCollection services , IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.Configure<MongoDatabaseOptions>(config.GetSection("MongoDatabase"));
            services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(provider => new MongoClient(config["MongoDatabase"]));

            var pack = new ConventionPack();
            pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());

            ConventionRegistry.Register("Custom Convention", pack, t => true);
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Recipe>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Title));
            });
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

I just create a repository on Github:
[myrepo](https://github.com/arifsamuel/ContosoRecipes)

Maybe someone can help, and contribute to the repo, it will be very helpful and much appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried the [official  tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)?

Comment: yes, already tried this one and just create a [repo](https://github.com/arifsamuel/BooksApi) for that:, but still missing some part above..